# Read html file and replace string in c

Tags: php, c, string, replace, utf-8

I need function to read html file (email template) and replace some string in that file. I already have some function for that but i think that function make html template look ugly when i send email. here is my function

```
    int send_formated_mail(char *to, struct mail_struct *mail, char *string)
{
    int retval;
    /* Open pipe to sendmail */
    sendmail_pipe=popen(sendmail_path, "w");
    if(sendmail_pipe == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No Pipe to \"sendmail\"\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fd = fopen(mail->mail_layout_path, "r");
    if(fd != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(sendmail_pipe,  "To: %s\r\n"
                    "From: %s\r\n"
                    "Reply-to: %s\r\n"
                    "Subject : %s\r\n"
                    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
                    "Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n\n",
                    to, from, reply_to, mail->subject);
        char buffer[255];
        memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(buffer));
        while(!feof(fd))
        {
            fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fd);
            fprintf(sendmail_pipe, "%s", replace_str(buffer, LINK, string));
            memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(buffer));
        }
        fflush(sendmail_pipe);
        retval = pclose(sendmail_pipe);
        fclose(fd);
        return retval;
    }
    return 1;
}

char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{
    static char buffer[4096];
    char *p;

    if(!(p = strstr(str, orig)))  // Is 'orig' even in 'str'?
        return str;

    strncpy(buffer, str, p-str); // Copy characters from 'str' start to 'orig' st$
    buffer[p-str] = '\0';

    sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig));

    return buffer;
}
```

Template is utf-8 charset and i need to send utf-8. Right now string is replaced but there are some errors with template, like charset is different. I know how to do this is php and in php it works well but i dont know in c...

any help is welcome!

p.s can i execute php file from this c function? so i dont need this replace and charset would be ok.

Comment: `fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fd);` this will not add a `'\0'` to buffer, so the string will not be null terminated, so you can't use string functions like `strncpy`.

Comment: What will happen when your searched string spans the `char buffer[255];` boundary?

Comment: Like i told you, i know basic of c. Searched string has only 7 chars, but string that will replace it can have up to 70.

Comment: get rid of `feof(fd)`.  Check the result of `fread()` instead to break loop.

Comment: where is the line: "FILE * sendmail_pipe = NULL;" ?  I do not see it in the presented code

Comment: string is a common class name in c++, so probably should not be used.

Comment: this line: sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig)); could overrun the 'buffer' array.  perhaps use: strncat( buffer, rep, (sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer)) );  strncat( buffer, (p+strlen(orig)), (sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer)) );

Comment: the function replace_str() can return two wildly different pointers, depending on if a string replacement is actually performed or not.  This could have subtle bugs (depending on the rest of the code) that would be very difficult to debug.

Comment: this line: while(!feof(fd))  the feof() condition is set as a result of the fread() so is undefined before then,  suggest re-design loop, perhaps using fread() instead of feof() as the loop control

Comment: this line: (inside a loop): fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fd); followed by this line: fprintf(sendmail_pipe, "%s", replace_str(buffer, LINK, string)); has some problems: 1) fread does not null terminate the read string 2) each line is (likely) to be different lengths, so the initial clearing of buffer to all '\0' does not mean the second line will be terminated at the proper location (I.E. could be left over garbage between the read line and the remaining '\0' in buffer:  always clear buffer to all '\0' just before the call to fread() rather than before the top of the loop

Comment: design suggestion: for read loop, while(1) { ... fread( fd); if(feof(fd)) { break; } ...

Comment: this line: to, from, reply_to, mail->subject); the variables 'from' and 'reply_to' are not defined within this function (I would have expected them to be defined withing the 'mail' struct or listed as parameters to the send_formated_mail() function

Comment: regarding the results of the call to pclose() being used as a return value.... Upon successful return, pclose() shall return the termination status of the command language interpreter. Otherwise, pclose() shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error.  As noted at: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pclose.html  and (in general) sub-functions should not return negative values.  currently the function: send_formated_mail() can return -1 or 0 or +1 or unknown.  And who knows what the command language interp. is going to return

Comment: @Rodjaaa let me rephrase my question. Suppose your search string is "abcdefg". You `fread` the first 255 file chars so that buffer[251..254] holds "abcd", and the next `fread` puts "efg" into buffer[0..2]. How do you detect and replace "abcdefg" when it spans a buffer boundary?

Comment: Now i replaced this whole function to: sprintf(string, "/usr/bin/php /path/to/script/ %s %s %s", param1, param2, param3); system(string);